# Render image in sonata admin List. [LiipImagineBundle]

Tags: php, symfony, twig, rendering, sonata-admin

I'm trying to render the image of my product in sonata admin list.

In my index page i'm rendering my product like this :

```
    {% for entity in entity %}
<span><img alt="airline" width="500" height="400" src="{{  entity.image.path}}" ></span>  
    {% endfor %}
```

I tried to do the same but it's doesn't work.

So i decided to install LiipImagineBundle and this what i did.

**ProductAdmin.php**

```
->add('image.id', null, array('template' => 'ApplicationSonataBackcommerceBundle::list_image.html.twig'))
```

**list_image.html.twig**

```
{% extends 'SonataAdminBundle:CRUD:base_list_field.html.twig' %}
{% block field%}
    <div>
    {% for entity in entity %}
        <img src="{{ entity.image.path | imagine_filter('productThumb') }}" />
    {% endfor %}
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

**config.yml**

```
liip_imagine:
    resolvers:
       default:
          web_path: ~

    filter_sets:
        cache: ~
        productThumb:
            quality: 90
            filters:
                thumbnail: { size: [47, 42], mode: outbound }
```

I have this error when i refresh the page:

> An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template
>   ("Notice: Undefined index: entity") in
>   ApplicationSonataBackcommerceBundle::list_image.html.twig at line 4.

***EDIT***

This is the full add method:

```
/**
 * @param \Sonata\AdminBundle\Datagrid\ListMapper $listMapper
 *
 * @return \Sonata\AdminBundle\Datagrid\ListMapper
 */
protected function configureListFields(ListMapper $listMapper)
{
    $listMapper
        ->addIdentifier('id')
        ->add('user.id')
        ->add('image.id', null, array('template' => 'ApplicationSonataBackcommerceBundle::list_image.html.twig'))
        ->add('airport', null, array('editable' => true))
        ->add('airport1', null, array('editable' => true))
        ->add('departuredate')
        ->add('arrivaldate')
        ->add('price')
        ->add('telephone', null, array('editable' => true))
        ->add('_action', 'actions', array(
    'actions' => array(
        'show' => array(),
        'edit' => array(),
        'delete' => array(),
        )

));
    return $listMapper;
}
```

This is the generated html of only two images :

```
    <td class="sonata-ba-list-field sonata-ba-list-field-integer" objectId="7">
           <div>
            <img src="http://127.0.0.1/symfony/web/app_dev.php/media/cache/resolve/productThumb/symfony/web/airline/Emirates.png" />
             </div>
    </td>


   <td class="sonata-ba-list-field sonata-ba-list-field-integer" objectId="9">
            <div>
            <img src="http://127.0.0.1/symfony/web/app_dev.php/media/cache/resolve/productThumb/symfony/web/airline/Singapore_Airlines.svg" />
              </div>
   </td>
```

Comment: You don't passed entity variable to you template. You can show full `add` method

Comment: i updated my post , you can check on top.

Comment: guys i'm still stuck. Please i need help.

Comment: I fink you simple don't passed entity variable search this place for passing

Answer (score 1):

**It's because you changed the `cache_prefix`.**

In the [original doc](https://github.com/liip/LiipImagineBundle#liipimaginebundle) , extract :

```
For example with this bundle the following is possible:

<img src="{{ '/relative/path/to/image.jpg' | imagine_filter('thumbnail') }}" />
```

The default cache prefix is : `cache_prefix: media/cache`
because it's generated in `www.yoursite/media/cache/`

You've changed by `/symfony/web/media/cache/cache/airline`

So if you send it by `{{ entity.image.path | imagine_filter('productThumb') }}` the path is not the wanted relative...

You send it now `/symfony/web/media/cache/cache/airline/your_image.jpg`

Comment: I have tried with your code and is already much more better. It showing that a image should be there but it doesn't show it. This is a screenshot so you can understand what i means: [Here](http://hpics.li/92e2d4a)

Comment: Sorry for the delay response. I tried many things but the image still doens't show.  First i noticed that the `media/cache`  folder wasn't generated. So i run the following command: `liip:imagine:cache:resolve airline/Emirates.png` . Now i have the folder generated. I decided to change the `cache_prefix` from `cache_prefix: media/cache` to `/symfony/web/media/cache/cache/airline`. I also run the following command `assets:install web/` . The image still doesn't appears. Check on top of my post there is the generated html.

Comment: you mean by the generated html -> the source code of the web page ?

Comment: Yes I would like to see if the what is in the src attribute of img tag. Maybe have you a loading error or something else... ?

Comment: This is what is in the src attribute =>`/symfony/web/app_dev.php/media/cache/productThumb/symfony/web/airline/Emirates.png"` but when i'm not using liip imagine is working fine =>      `<span><img alt="airline" width="150" height="80" src="{{object.image.path}}" ></span>`

Comment: It's because you've changed the cache_prefix. You've to send the relative path to the bundle, not the absolute. In changing media/cache, by symfony... you destroy the wanted relative path...

Comment: ok. i removed `cache_prefix: symfony/web/media/cache/cache/airline` and i put `cache_prefix: media/cache` but still doesn't work , i also tried with `web_path: ~` without cache_prefix but still doesn't work.

Comment: ok what's the generated ? (it's long long ;-) ), and what's the error in your console ? 404 not found ?

Comment: this is the link generated: `http://127.0.0.1/symfony/web/app_dev.php/media/cache/resolve/productThumb/symfony/web/airline/Emirates.png` yes the error is 404 (impossible to load picture). when i inspect the element (src) and i change the link to `http://127.0.0.1/symfony/web/app_dev.php/media/cache/resolve/productThumb/airline/Emirates.png` It's work fine.

Comment: I don't understand why after `productThumb` there is /symfony/web ......it should be productThumb/airline/Emirates.png.  i think i will just render my image like this : `<span><img alt="airline" width="150" height="80" src="{{object.image.path}}" ></span>` i won't use liip imagine , it's just doesn't work :( . Thank you so much for your help.i really appreciate it. :)